# Get GUID of a monitor?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to save certain settings of my program to the registry based on the monitor being used.  To do this, I need to obtain a unique identifier for the monitor to ensure unintentional duplicates never occur (instead of using //./DISPLAY1 or the device string).

Is there a way to obtain the GUID of the primary monitor on Windows, using either Win32 or DXGI?

Comment: Who says there is one?  There's a device path assigned to the device node created to represent the monitor, but it's not guaranteed to recognize when the monitor has been changed.  Providing EDID data is not mandatory, and some display connections don't support DDC anyway.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7269216/103167 considering that the EDID serial number is the only way Windows would know to change your imagined GUID.